# More efficient way to join 60+ 1000KB CSV files than per row SQL joins?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Is there a more efficient way to join 60 csv files of size 1000KB?

I have multiple time series csv files that must be merged based on a shared column, I am currently writing all data to SQL tables and joining tables based on the shared column 1 row at a time because the join operation could not be done in memory with pandas.

My current method's run time for joining SQL tables 1 row at a time seems to expand as time goes on, becoming increasingly slow after 3000x lines, while some datasets have more than 40000 lines.

Comment: In the **REAL** old days before data bases you would sort all your .CSVs on the common key, open all the files at once (or as many as you could), then write code to replenish each line in its order as you consumed them.

Comment: None of what you're saying here seems to make any sense. **(1)** 60 * 1000KB = 60MB. Most of my cellphone applications are bigger than that. Any personal computer today has at least 4GB RAM.  **(2)** "1 row at a time"? Seriously?!

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz thanks for the reminder that the files do in fact fit in memory. I re-attempted to join all tables in 1 go and it works now, I am however still unsure why the script hanged on previous attempts.

Comment: Can anyone explain why joining row by row seems to slow down exponentially with increase in row number, especially past the 3000x entry?

Comment: Well, we have know idea how you implemented “joining row by row". The concept is bad enough to begin with.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I did something along the lines of:

left join x from table 1, x2 from table 2, ... xi from table i 
limit; {offset}, {#rows};

Comment: joining row by row will be exponentially slower the more rows you have as each read and write action takes around the quoter of the second (+-, depends on the hardware and the code).